# CSS min-height not keeping divs inline

Tags: html, css

I am using this CSS Code with media queries:

```
.clearfloat {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
.box-container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.icon-box {
    width:32%;
    max-width:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .icon-box {
        width:290px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .icon-box {
        width:270px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 880px) {
    .clearfloat {
        display:none;
    }
    .icon-box {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto 0 auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
}
```

i want to have a min-height for each box but when i add it, the boxes don't display inline

here is a Fiddle with the full CSS and HTML Code: http://jsfiddle.net/aAtk5/1/

Comment: What is the min-height you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Setting min-height to `.icon-box` seems to work fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/aAtk5/5/

```
.icon-box {
    min-height:50px;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/aAtk5/4/ - i have added just a height rather than min-height and the text is not displaying inside the div

Comment: because the text `overflows`, in windows chrome, the revision 4, changing height (which is fixed), for min-height (which isn't) looks good to me

Comment: @charlie See updated answer, I mean the fiddle link.

Comment: what happened to the divs displaying inline?

Comment: @charlie isn't this the required O/P, are we missing anything.

Comment: it needs to be like: http://jsfiddle.net/aAtk5/6/ but with the text inside the divs

Comment: ok, I can help you if you can make me understand lil better, am getting confused, since you are blindly mentioning text and you seem to have entirely text.

Comment: lol sorry - on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aAtk5/6/ the first .icon-box has text in but its overlapping the bottom of the .icon-box div (not displaying within the border)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40503/discussion-between-venomvendor-and-charlie)

Comment: @charlie You have height at 100px, this forces the text to overflow. If you would like it to be 100px and still scroll set the overflow: scroll property.